# Reffering to an xml-element from an xml-element-ref between separate xml binding files

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have two eclipselink moxy binding files because I want to add binding metadata for classes coming from two different packages. The problem is, that I want to refer to an `xml-element` defined in binding xml file `B.xml` from an `xml-element-ref` defined in binding xml file `A.xml`.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special that needs to be done.  Just make sure when you bootstrap the MOXy `JAXBContext` that you bring in both external mapping documents.  See below for an example:

```
package forum10874711;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

import forum10874711.b.B;

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        List<String> metadata = new ArrayList<String>(2);
        metadata.add("forum10874711/a/binding2.xml");
        metadata.add("forum10874711/b/binding2.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, metadata);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {B.class}, properties);

    }

}
```

**Note:**

The above code was taken from my answer to one of your other questions (that includes a full example):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879080/383861