# Inheritance mapping throwing an exception with MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2, moxy

I followed the second option mentioned in [JAXB inheritance in MOXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874711/jaxb-inheritance-in-moxy) to map my parent class and child class listed below. MOXy is throwing the below exception and not sure what the issue is

**Parent class**

```
public class UnitedStatesAddressData extends AbstractAddress implements UnitedStatesAddress, Serializable, Cloneable
{
    private String primaryAddress;

    public String getPrimaryAddress()
    {
        return primaryAddress;
    }

    public void setPrimaryAddress(final String primaryAddress)
    {
        this.primaryAddress = primaryAddress;
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData extends UnitedStatesAddressData implements TokenizedUnitedStatesAddress,
        CloneableAddress
{
    private String houseNumber;

    private String preDirectional;

    private String streetName;

    private String streetType;

//getters and setters ignored
}
```

**external binding file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4" package-name="com.abc.ic.domain.impl.country.us" xml-accessor-type="PROPERTY">
   <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://xml.abc.com/XMLSchema/InterConnect">
      <!-- Do not specify 'prefix'. We doesn't want the namespace prefix in our instance documents as they increase the payload size. -->
      <xml-ns namespace-uri="http://xml.abc.com/XMLSchema/InterConnect" />
   </xml-schema>
   <java-types>
      <java-type name="TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData">
         <xml-root-element name="USAddress" />
         <xml-type prop-order="preDirectional houseNumber streetName streetType postDirection unitDesignator apartmentNumber primaryAddress secondaryAddress cityName stateAbbreviation zipCode" />
         <java-attributes>
            <xml-element name="StreetPreDirection" java-attribute="preDirectional" />
            <xml-element name="StreetNumber" java-attribute="houseNumber" />
            <xml-element name="StreetName" java-attribute="streetName" />
            <xml-element name="StreetType" java-attribute="streetType" />
            <xml-element name="StreetPostDirection" java-attribute="postDirection" />
            <xml-element name="UnitDesignator" java-attribute="unitDesignator" />
            <xml-element name="UnitNumber" java-attribute="apartmentNumber" />
            <xml-element name="AddressLine1" java-attribute="primaryAddress" />
            <xml-element name="AddressLine2" java-attribute="secondaryAddress" />
            <xml-element name="City" java-attribute="cityName" />
            <xml-element name="State" java-attribute="stateAbbreviation" />
            <xml-element name="PostalCode" java-attribute="zipCode" />
         </java-attributes>
      </java-type>
      <java-type name="UnitedStatesAddressData" xml-transient="true">
         <xml-root-element />
      </java-type>
   </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**Error**

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The property or field primaryAddress is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The property or field primaryAddress is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:331)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at com.abc.ic.platform.sts.domain.transformation.response.JaxbTest.beforeClass(JaxbTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-50009] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The property or field primaryAddress is annotated to be transient so can not be included in the proporder annotation.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.transientInProporder(JAXBException.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.TypeInfo.setProperties(TypeInfo.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.XMLProcessor.processXML(XMLProcessor.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:904)
    ... 28 more
```

**UPDATE**

I've tested this by removing "prop-order" and this works fine **except that I can no longer control the order of the elements in generated XML**. I believe this is a bug in the code.

Comment: Created a Bug for EclipseLink/Moxy - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for this is that the  child class overrides the method from parent class as sown below but since the parent class has been defined to be xml-transient="true", the below check from TypeInfo is failing.

**child class overriding getPrimaryAddress**

```
public class TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData extends UnitedStatesAddressData implements TokenizedUnitedStatesAddress,
        CloneableAddress
{
@override
public String getPrimaryAddress()
{
   return primaryAddress;
}
}
```

**TypeInfo.java offending code**

```
if (p.isTransient() && propOrderList.contains(p.getPropertyName()))
{
throw org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.transientInProporder(p.getPropertyName());
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

The issue is not with the AbstractAddress. After some debugging, the issue seems to be with the below logic in the `AnnotationProcessor.getPropertyPropertiesForClass(final JavaClass cls, final TypeInfo info, final boolean onlyPublic, final boolean onlyExplicit)`

```
if ((setMethod == null) && !(hasJAXBAnnotations(getMethod)))
{
    // if there's no corresponding setter, and not explicitly
    // annotated, don't process
    isPropertyTransient = true;
}
```

This method will **tag** any method that doesn't have *both* the get/set methods defined as "transient". In my case, I override just the `getPrimaryAddress()` method in `TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData` class and not the corresponding setter. And hence the `Annotationprocessor` is designating it as a **transient** property neglecting the fact that this method is being overridden.

**FIX**

The issue is fixed after making sure that the overridden methods are properly handled in the transient check as shown below

```
if ((setMethod == null) && !(hasJAXBAnnotations(getMethod)))
{
    if (!isMethodOverrriden(cls.getQualifiedName(), getMethod.getName()))
    {
        // if there's no corresponding setter, and not explicitly
        // annotated, don't process
        isPropertyTransient = true;
    }
}

public static boolean isMethodOverrriden(final String classQualifiedName, final String methodName)
    {
        Method myMethod;
        try
        {
            myMethod = Class.forName(classQualifiedName).getMethod(methodName, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Class<?> declaringClass = myMethod.getDeclaringClass();
        if (declaringClass.equals(Object.class))
        {
            return false;
        }

        Class<?> superclass = declaringClass.getSuperclass();
        if (superclass == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                superclass.getMethod(myMethod.getName(), myMethod.getParameterTypes());
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                // recursively check all super classes
                isMethodOverrriden(superclass.getName(), methodName);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a bug, the problem is that in your model `AbstractAddress` is still a mapped class.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11908405/383861

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have marked `UnitedStatesAddressData` as `@XmlTransient` (using MOXy's external mapping document), it's super class `AbstractAddress` is still a mapped class.  As such properties from `AbstractAddress` can not be specified in the `propOrder` setting for `TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData`.  The solution will be to make `AbstractAddress` `@XmlTransient` as well.

**Fix**

I have modified your mapping document to do this below assuming that the `AbstractAddress` class is in the same package as the rest of your domain model.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4" package-name="com.abc.ic.domain.impl.country.us" xml-accessor-type="PROPERTY">
   <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://xml.abc.com/XMLSchema/InterConnect">
      <!-- Do not specify 'prefix'. We doesn't want the namespace prefix in our instance documents as they increase the payload size. -->
      <xml-ns namespace-uri="http://xml.abc.com/XMLSchema/InterConnect" />
   </xml-schema>
   <java-types>
      <java-type name="TokenizedUnitedStatesAddressData">
         <xml-root-element name="USAddress" />
         <xml-type prop-order="preDirectional houseNumber streetName streetType postDirection unitDesignator apartmentNumber primaryAddress secondaryAddress cityName stateAbbreviation zipCode" />
         <java-attributes>
            <xml-element name="StreetPreDirection" java-attribute="preDirectional" />
            <xml-element name="StreetNumber" java-attribute="houseNumber" />
            <xml-element name="StreetName" java-attribute="streetName" />
            <xml-element name="StreetType" java-attribute="streetType" />
            <xml-element name="StreetPostDirection" java-attribute="postDirection" />
            <xml-element name="UnitDesignator" java-attribute="unitDesignator" />
            <xml-element name="UnitNumber" java-attribute="apartmentNumber" />
            <xml-element name="AddressLine1" java-attribute="primaryAddress" />
            <xml-element name="AddressLine2" java-attribute="secondaryAddress" />
            <xml-element name="City" java-attribute="cityName" />
            <xml-element name="State" java-attribute="stateAbbreviation" />
            <xml-element name="PostalCode" java-attribute="zipCode" />
         </java-attributes>
      </java-type>
      <java-type name="UnitedStatesAddressData" xml-transient="true">
         <xml-root-element />
      </java-type>
      <java-type name="AbstractAddress" xml-transient="true">
         <xml-root-element />
      </java-type>
   </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with the new finding. The issue is not with the AbstractAddress but with the AnnotationProcessor ignoring the overridden methods